# Reusing timer in android

Tags: android, timer

In my android app, I have the following relevant piece of code:

```
/*Code outside*/    
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask(){
                public void run(){
                    stuffToBeDone();
                }
            },someVariableDelay,someVariablePeriod);
    }
}
```

Everything was going fine until I noticed that *stuffToBeDone()* was running once for every time I pressed the button. As far as I understand, every time *onClick()* is called and the old Timer should not exist anymore, but somehow the TimerTask survives.

In the second button click, I no longer have a reference to the first Timer to *cancel()* it (because it should not exist anymore). And if I declare the Timer as a *final* variable in the *Code outside* so that I can do it, after canceling I cannot reuse it anymore. So how can I terminate that TimerTask but then still be able to use a Timer?

Comment: You can delcare  `Timer t`  as a instance variable initialize in `onCreate` on button click schedule the timer task and then you can call `cancel()` any time you want

Comment: @Raghunandan In the penultimate sentence I point that if I do so I cannot reuse it anymore. But it should be in the final question for more clarity, I think.

Comment: by reuse what you mean. You can remember the old value cancel the timer and start again with old value

Comment: @Raghunandan If I *cancel()* it, I cannot use the Timer anymore. So I would have to create another Timer. And here we go again...

Comment: You can cancel the timer. Re-Read my first comment. More importantly what does   `stuffToBeDone();` do. There might be alternatives to timer task

Comment: @Raghunandan I think I got what you mean, I did not see the *instance* part (I was putting *t* in onCreate(), so I was forced to *final* it, and that caused me problems). If I do so, it does not complain anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Timer is thread based from the Android Developers website:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

> When a timer is no longer needed, users should call cancel(), which releases the timer's thread and other resources. Timers not explicitly cancelled may hold resources indefinitely.

I would recommend instantiating the timer inside the onclicklistener only i.e. something similar to this:

```
    /*Code outside*/    
Timer t = null;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(t == null)
           t = new Timer();
        else
           t.cancel();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask(){
                public void run(){
                    stuffToBeDone();
                }
            },someVariableDelay,someVariablePeriod);
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to do that, *t* must be a final variable. But if it is a final variable, I cannot assign it to be a new timer inside the *onClick()* event.

Comment: @chubakueno why final? check the java docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing. You declare the `Timer timer` before onCreate as a instance variable.

Comment: Why not put Timer t declaration inside the class definition of the OnClickListener?

Comment: Shoudn't that be *else{ t.cancel(); t= new Timer();}* ?